# notifying entity call back methods after bulk query in jpa

Tags: jpa, callback, ejb

How does jpa entity call back method work?
are they only notified when doing single jpa operations like `em.merge()` and `em.create()` ? or they will be notified if i use `em.createQuery().executeUpdate()`? (also for namedQueries)

Can i use them instead of real database triggers?

Comment: If my answer is OK, you can mark it also as accepted. This will show that your question does not need any attention anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a direct statement, but from the quote below (JPA 2.1 spec, 
`Chapter 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations`), I understand that in a BULK update or delete, the listeners are not called, because the persistence context won't see the changed entities:

> [In a bulk update or bulk delete] The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the
>   bulk update or delete.

So the answer is: only in single JPA operations will the listeners be changed.

A listener is not the same as a database trigger: a constraint of JPA listeners is that you should not change relationships or other entities inside them (although some JPA providers may support this).